# How I can add highlight effect on outside the area of selection with CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a box like concept below when hovering with mouse it will show other buttons and have highlight effect in outside the area of selection box:
[image: highlight effect with CSS]

So how I can achieve it to add highlight effect in outside the area of selection box just with either pure css or jquery?

Comment: @ZainFarooq its not just simple like do you think

Comment: Mohammad Reza answered it very well. You can get help from his post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 (with jQuery):**

HTML:

```
<div class="box">text</div>
<div class="box">text</div>
<div class="box">text</div>
<div class="box">text</div>
```

CSS (only for this example):

```
.box{
    transition:.3s;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
}
.box.fade{
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.box').not($(this)).addClass('fade');
});

$('.box').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.box').not($(this)).removeClass('fade');
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k71fqn4o/1/

**Solution 2 (pure css):**

If you have container for your boxes so you can use this solution, but **solution 1** is safer.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">text</div>
    <div class="box">text</div>
    <div class="box">text</div>
    <div class="box">text</div>
</div>
```

CSS (only for this example):

```
.box{
    transition:.3s;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
}
.container:hover .box{
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: .3s;
}

.box:hover{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ogvudr5t/

Comment: Why use JS when `:hover` is available in CSS?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan With hover you can't access to other elements. In this case you have to use js for adding a class to other elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I add another solution with pure css.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the highlight effect using the `box-shadow` CSS property (and associated vendor prefixes). The other elements can also be faded in using the `:hover` pseudo selector and the `animate` rule. Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border, box-shadow 0.2s;
  padding: 5px;
}
div button {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
div:hover {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
div:hover button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Foo</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

[Box-shadow](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) should do the trick.

Comment: That will achieve the highlight, but what about fading in/out the button?